# dynamically adding textbox and saving data in textbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add a textbox dynamically at runtime and saving data in SQL Server. I'm able to generate a textbox, but I'm not able send data to the database and it is not giving any error. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="btnAddCtrl" runat="server" Text="Add New Field" OnClick="btnAddCtrl_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

and here is my cs code

```
protected void btnAddCtrl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowCount = 0;

    //initialize a session.
    rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks"]);

    rowCount++;

    //In each button clic save the numbers into the session.
    Session["clicks"] = rowCount;

    //Create the textboxes and labels each time the button is clicked.
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        TextBox TxtBoxU = new TextBox();
        //TextBox TxtBoxE = new TextBox();

        Label lblU = new Label();
        //Label lblE = new Label();

        TxtBoxU.ID = "TextBoxU" + i.ToString();
        //TxtBoxE.ID = "TextBoxE" + i.ToString();

        lblU.ID = "LabelU" + i.ToString();
        //lblE.ID = "LabelE" + i.ToString();

        lblU.Text = "User " + (i + 1).ToString() + " : ";
        //lblE.Text = "E-Mail : ";

        //Add the labels and textboxes to the Panel.
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lblU);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(TxtBoxU);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
    }
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TextBox textBox in Panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AssetsDetail (FieldName) VALUES(@FieldName)",con))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FieldName", textBox.Text);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Dynamic controls are not part of the markup, they need to be added programmatically to the control tree on each page load, only after which they will be rendered back in the HTML response.

In this case, you are not adding the controls on the PostBack caused by Save Click. Hence, controls are not part of the Control Tree and `Panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()` count will always be zero. In fact the textbox wont even be rendered after the SaveClick postback.

You need to have "Adding dynamic control's code"(except for 'rowcount' increment) on each postback, so that TextBoxes will be available in `Panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()` and textbox 'Text' will be present.

```
        private void CreateDynamicControls(bool incrementRowCount = false)
    {
        int rowCount = 0;

        //initialize a session.
        rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks"]);

        if (incrementRowCount)
            rowCount++;

        Session["clicks"] = rowCount;

        //Create the textboxes and labels each time the button is clicked.
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            TextBox TxtBoxU = new TextBox();
            //TextBox TxtBoxE = new TextBox();

            Label lblU = new Label();
            //Label lblE = new Label();

            TxtBoxU.ID = "TextBoxU" + i.ToString();
            //TxtBoxE.ID = "TextBoxE" + i.ToString();

            lblU.ID = "LabelU" + i.ToString();
            //lblE.ID = "LabelE" + i.ToString();

            lblU.Text = "User " + (i + 1).ToString() + " : ";
            //lblE.Text = "E-Mail : ";

            //Add the labels and textboxes to the Panel.
            Panel1.Controls.Add(lblU);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(TxtBoxU);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
            Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If PostBack caused by btnAddCtrl, it will take care of adding controls
        if (Page.Request.Params.AllKeys.Contains("btnAddCtrl"))
            return;

        CreateDynamicControls();           
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnAddCtrl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateDynamicControls(true);
    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TextBox textBox in Panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: thnx pal. i got your point. but how do i achieve what u r saying. can u show me plz.thnx

Comment: Hey Zain. Added the code that worked for me. Cheers.

Comment: hey boney thnx a bundles...i tried it worked. but now it is regenerating the previously generated controls as well on postback. why is that happening??

Answer (score 0):

In order to retain the dynamic TextBoxes across PostBacks, we need to make use of Page’s PreInit event to recreate the dynamic TextBoxes using the Request.Form collection.
First all the keys containing the string TextBoxU are fetched and then for each key the btnAddCtrl_Click event is called.

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> keys = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(key => key.Contains("TextBoxU")).ToList();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string key in keys)
    {
        this.CreateTextBox("TextBoxU" + i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi! i am using this code.but i am getting error"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." while adding second control .